# Rails: HOST Header Attack vulnerability

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx

I'm quite concerned about the security of the web apps I build, so I've been using various tools to crawl each one of my apps.

Whilst everything that can be done in term of programming, and is not foreseen by the ready classes, like Active Record, is done, there is one issue I keep getting alerts for which I do not know where to start fixing this.

I'm running `Unicorn` behind `Nginx` and `Rails 4.1`. The alert I keep getting is this:

```
    An attacker can manipulate the Host header as seen by the 
web application and cause the application to behave in 
unexpected ways. Developers often resort to the exceedingly 
untrustworthy HTTP Host header (_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] in PHP). 
Even otherwise-secure applications trust this value enough to 
write it to the page without HTML-encoding it with code equivalent to:

<link href="https://_SERVER['HOST']" (Joomla)

...and append secret keys and tokens to links containing it:

(Django, Gallery, others)

....and even directly import scripts from it:

(Various)
```

The following recommendation is issued:

```
The web application should use the SERVER_NAME instead
of the Host header. It should also create a dummy vhost 
that catches all requests with unrecognized Host headers. 
This can also be done under Nginx by specifying a non-wildcard 
SERVER_NAME, and under Apache by using a non-wildcard serverName 
and turning the UseCanonicalName directive on. Consult references 
for detailed information.
```

Sure, whatever.. This vulnarability as I understand is generically harmless but could be harmful in a variety of web applications, depending on their kind.

What do I do to block this kind of attack? Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found a way to bypass the behavior and stop getting the alerts. I don't know if this is the best way to do it, so comments, suggestions and new answers are accepted.

Here we go.

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    before_action :debug_headers

private
    def debug_headers
        if request.env['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST']
            request.env.except!('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST') # just drop the variable
        end
    end # def

end # class
```

Answer (score 3):

Allowing suspect requests to reach your code is not a best practice; you leave yourself open to all attacks you haven't yet heard of. Host header spoofing can cause very serious problems, and these attacks should be prevented. That being said, this answer may be better placed in ServerFault ;).

One popular and easy fix is to avoid the problem altogether by simply ignoring incoming requests that have suspicious host headers. In security speak, you want to ignore every request that comes in that has a host header that doesn't exactly match your system. In Nginx, this is done by setting up a default server on port 80 (and port 443 if you use HTTPS) that does nothing but return 444 (A non-standard Nginx code that translates roughly into "COLD SHOULDER"):

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen 443 default_server;
    return 444;
}
```

One issue with this is that some hosting solutions, like AWS, provide an automatic health/latency checking with a dynamic IP address in the host header. If you drop these requests, your instance will be dropped from your load balancer and you can't access your site from the web browser. You will need to put logic in your default server to pass these requests and ignore all others.

Answer (score 0):

This might be better as some sort of middleware:

```
# config/environments/production.rb

config.action_controller.default_url_options = { host: "example.com" }
```

and:

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :protect_from_host_header_attack

  def protect_from_host_header_attack
    env['HTTP_HOST'] = default_url_options.fetch(:host, env['HTTP_HOST'])
  end
end
```